# How to handle onclick for disappearing elements with react-spring?

Tags: reactjs

I have an app where I have a horizontal list of items, that when you click them they should disappear and trigger some action. Minimal demonstration here:
Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/5xpkn3nzxl

Try clicking away the head of the list fairly quickly until there are none remaining. Notice how the event generated doesn't match what it looks like you are clicking on, and you end up with duplicates. Expected output would be only one event per item, and that click events over the top of a remaining item should go to that item, rather than the one that is disappearing. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but I'm looking for suggestions on how best to handle.

(I'm open to suggestions of other libraries also if they handle this better than react-spring.)

Comment: Unimportant to your problem, but there is a warning telling you to use `className`, not `class` on line 34.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. When I click your examples, I appear to be getting the correct events. `hello 1` logs `{ key: 1, text: 'hello 1' }` The only issue I see is that you can click the same one multiple times. Is that what your issue is?

Comment: correct, you shouldn't be able to click any item more than once. After you click it it should "disappear". Notice in particular that right near the end of the disappear animation, when the item is basically invisible and your pointer is clearly over the next item, clicks will still register to the invisible item, which is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an early return to your `clickHandler` if you find the `item` is already in `this.state.clicked`.

```
clickHandler(item) {
    if (this.state.clicked.some(clickedItem => item.key === clickedItem.key)) {
        return;
    }
    return (e) => {
        this.setState({
            clicked: this.state.clicked.concat([item]),
            items: this.state.items.filter((x) => x.key != item.key)
        });
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: this correctly prevents duplicate submissions, thank you! I still couldn't click the next element, but by adding z-index to my list of styles and making it negative when disappearing, I was able to get correct behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/ymok7023lz